# Changing the time step value to a variable for a Keras LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

The question is quite simple and I have searched the internet wide and thin for a solution. How do I reshape a dataframe to have a custom time step that I feed the LSTM?

```
look_back=90
train_X = np.reshape(
    train_dataset, (train_dataset.shape[0], look_back, train_dataset.shape[1]))
test_X = np.reshape(
    test_dataset, (test_dataset.shape[0], look_back, `test_dataset.shape[1]))
```

The above throws the following error ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 446208 into shape (3984,90,112)
So how do I change the look-back to a variable without it being 1 and thereby rendering the memory feature of an LSTM useless.

**EDIT**
Using the solution provided below I change my code to

```
## train test split
train_split = 0.8
train_size = int(n_sample*train_split)

X_train = X[:train_size] # (train_size, n_features)
X_test = X[train_size:] # (n_sample-train_size, n_features)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape) 
y_train = y[:train_size] # (train_size,)
y_test = y[train_size:] # (n_sample-train_size,)
print(y_train.shape, y_test.shape) 

look_back = 90
y_train = y_train[look_back:] # (train_size-look_back,)
y_test = y_test[look_back:] # ((n_sample-train_size),)
print(y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
X_train = view_as_windows(X_train, (look_back,n_features))[:-1,0] # (train_size-look_back, look_back, n_features)
X_test = view_as_windows(X_test, (look_back,n_features))[:-1,0] # ((n_sample-train_size)-look_back, look_back, n_features)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape)
```

It now works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a trick I suggest u to create sliding windows...

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

## create dummy data
n_sample = 2000
n_features = 5

X = np.tile(np.arange(n_sample), (n_features,1)).T

X_train = X[:int(n_sample*0.8)]
X_test = X[int(n_sample*0.8):]

## create windows
look_back = 90
X_train = view_as_windows(X_train, (look_back,n_features), step=1)[:-1,0]
X_test = view_as_windows(X_test, (look_back,n_features), step=1)[:-1,0]
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape) # (1510, 90, 5) (310, 90, 5)
```

Comment: I posted a comment sorry, stackoverflow was going over the character limit. Check my post's new comment

Comment: I have added my error and code to the following pastebin since StackOverflow wont allow me to post such a large comment:

https://pastebin.com/gWyVdA4A

I tried changing the look back period to 1 which is what it was hardcoded to before, it still throws the same error.

Comment: @sword134 here a complete working example... don't forget to upvote and accept as answer ;-) https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Wktg_XjHMlTAuF2pHu5iMovvHFaQmRuL?usp=sharing

Comment: Actually @Marco Cerliani how does it work with the look back period for an LSTM when the data is shuffled? My data is a multivariate timeseries sorted by dates, so if I have a look back of 90 will it look back 90 days in time or 90 rows? Because the difference is huge if it shuffles the data to be
2010-2-26
2008-3-09
2020-9-18

Because if the above is my row structure after shuffling and it looks back over the rows and not by the sorted dates, then it means that its going to use future data for its training of the present.

Comment: Also even though that I have a look back period of lets say 90 days, is it then still recommended to lag the data before feeding it to the model? So having a few extra columns of t-1, t-2. t-3 etc. or will the LSTM automatically carry out this with the 90 days look back period?

Comment: the look back is by row which is also by time if your data is sorted by date... using a time series model shuffling the data/window lost the time dependency resulting in distorted predictive power. I suggest u to simple split the data by date

Comment: Ok thank you, this has been a great help! But regarding adding lagged columns would one do it or just leave it to the look-back period of the LSTM?

Comment: no, don't add lag features... I suggest u to remain with the original ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216741/discussion-between-sword134-and-marco-cerliani).